# Joi validation Error message for required param inside object

Tags: node.js, express, joi

First of all Hello,

I work on an API with Node, Express & Mongoose. I also use Joi param validation to validate my param, but I have a problem with the error message when a required param inside an object is missing.

See exemple below :

my `param-validation.js`

```
body: {
        nameBusiness: Joi.string().required(),
        street: Joi.string().required(),
        cityName: Joi.string().required(),
        zipCode: Joi.number().required(),
        account: Joi.object({
            birthday: Joi.number().required(),
            firstName: Joi.string().required(),
            lastName: Joi.string().required(),
            email: Joi.string().regex(/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/).required(),
        }).required()
    }
```

My problem is when I make a request without the field "firstName" the error is :
`"\"firstName\" is required` but I think it's not clear for me the error should be : `"\"account.firstName\" is required`.

Someone know how Joi can display this error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, default message will be the same as you are mentioning. For complete path such as "account.firstName" you have look for path key in error object.

You can find his property in "validationErrorObject" like:-

```
if(validationResult.error){
validationResult.error.details.forEach(function(error){
    if(error.path.length > 1){
        console.log(error.path.join("."));
    }else{
      console.log(error.path[0]);
    }    
});
```

}